# Key press detection triggers high CPU usage

Tags: python, keypress

I need to detect a keypress and I am using the `keyboard` module to do that:

```py
while True:
    try:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('y'):
            pass
```

Unfortunately, this triggers high CPU usage. Is there a better way?

Comment: That's a busy-loop, so it certainly will be CPU heavy. What exactly is your end goal? Detect a keypress system-wide? For what purpose?

Answer (score 1):

It seems your loop should be blocked for a while to save CPU processing cost try the following approach

```
import time
while True:
    time.sleep(0.01)
    try:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('y'):
            pass
```

Also you can use [pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news) to detect key stokes so that it is even more optimized way, as far as i know pygame does not consume much cpu unless some thing is very promising.